# How To Create MessageBox or Dialog Box in design MVVM pattern application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parent-child, dialog

To those who are MVVM Purist, my question is, Is there a more simplistic, user readable,and unit testable code solution to the problem "How to create message box or dialog box in MVVM design pattern application" then what I come up with here? Disclaimer, I'm not a MVVM Purist and I will add a few lines of code in the View's code-behind if it means more simplistic, user readable and unit testable code. My solution builds upon what [awardcoder.blogspot suggested](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.nl/2012/03/showing-message-box-from-viewmodel-in.html). The first thing on notice in the solution is there is View's code-behind for handling MessageBox. From this point, I realize the fact that adding code in the View's code-behind is already heading down a not MVVM Purist path. Therefore, my solution take full advantage of this single rule breakage without additional rule breaking.

**BaseModel.cs**

```
 public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**MessageBoxModel.cs**

```
 public class MessageBoxModel : BaseModel
{
    private string msgboxcontent;

    public string MsgBoxContent
    {
        get
        {
            return msgboxcontent;
        }
        set
        {
            this.msgboxcontent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MsgBoxContent");
        }
    }
}
```

**MessageBoxViewModel.cs** // Child View-Model

```
public class MessageBoxViewModel
{
    private MessageBoxModel MB;


    public MessageBoxViewModel()
    {
        MB = new MessageBoxModel();
        MB.msgboxcontent = "My Message Box Content";
    }

    public MessageBoxModel MessageBoxModel
    {
        get
        {
            return MB;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs** // Parent View-Model

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private MessageBoxViewModel child_MsgBoxviewmodel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        child_MsgBoxviewmodel = new MessageBoxViewModel();

    }


    public MessageBoxViewModel MsgBoxViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return child_MsgBoxviewmodel;
        }    
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** //Parent View

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

    }


    private void MessageBoxButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the dialog box
        MessageBoxView dlgView = new MessageBoxView();

        // Call parent view model to get child view model
        MainWindowViewModel mvm = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        // Configure the dialog box
        dlgView.DataContext = mvm.MsgBoxViewModel ;

        // Open the dialog/message box 
        dlgView.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**MessageBoxView.xaml.cs** //Child View

```
 public partial class MessageBoxView : Window
{

    public MessageBoxView()
    {   //DialogBox
        InitializeComponent();


    }
}
```

The xmal files are not shown here because that one of the advantage of using MVVM. View styling is all up to the UI designer.

The message box will appear once someone click on the messageboxbutton.

Unit testing can then be done as usual on the model and viewmodel classes without worrying about popup windows during the test.

*JP*

Answer (score 0):

Let me say first that I am also not a MVVM Purist but I can already spot one thing that from my point of view I would change in your code.

- The button click event you have there should change to a binding in xaml to a ICommand of you MainWindowViewModel.

This will allow you to completely remove that code behind code, in the future you may also apply contracts (interfaces) with this approach to make your solution even more extensible :)

Cheers!